# Binding errors in functions with pointer parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

When writing a code this way...

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int data;

    Node(int data) {
        this->data = data;
    }
};

void display(const Node* &p){
    cout<<p->data<<endl;
}

int main(){
    Node *p = new Node(10);
    display(p);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error.

> `error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'const Node*&' to an rvalue of type 'const Node*'`

However, this works if the parameter `const Node* &p` of function `display` is changed to `Node* &p`.

Can someone explain to me how this works?

Comment: Don't use [#include<bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Why even use `const Node* &` instead of `const Node*` or `const Node&`? It seems that you do not want to modify where `p` points to in your `display` function.

Comment: @Zaiborg , yes I don't want to modify the pointer p and it's pointed memory location in the `display` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` is a `Node *` and can't be bound to `const Node* &` directly. It needs to be converted to `const Node*` firstly, which is a temporary, i.e. an rvalue, and can't be bound to lvaue-reference to non-const.

Changing to `Node* &` fixes the issue, `p` could be bound to `Node* &` directly without any implicit conversion.

BTW temporaries could be bound to lvalue-reference to `const`. Changing parameter type to `const Node* const &` works fine. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WPqbsoWZgOlNbBXs)

Or change from pass-by-reference to pass-by-value (the pointer itself) as `const Node*`. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BHAcrYgn50ppIhCg)

Comment: So, the pointer was actually not being passed as a constant pointer but a pointer to a constant memory location?

Comment: @VishalMahavar Yes, (read from right to left) `const Node* &` is a reference to (non-const) pointer to `const` `Node`.

Comment: But the conversion is from a non-constant memory location to a constant memory location. So, is the conversion prohibited or the reason to the error is something different?

Comment: @VishalMahavar No, `Node*` could be converted to `const Node*` implicitly, definately. The problem is the converted `const Node*` is a temporary, an rvalue which can't be bound to the reference. If the parameter type is a non-reference like `const Node*`, then it'll be fine. The converted `const Node*` will be passed to `display` (copied as parameter).

Comment: so it is different from passing normal parameters, for example, a `int` can be passed into a function accepting parameters as `const int &`. But this doesn't work with pointers ig.

Comment: @VishalMahavar `const int &` is reference to `const`, passing `int` to `const int&` works fine. For pointer version it would be passing `Node*` to `Node* const&` (reference to const pointer to non-const), which works fine too. Note that it's different with `const Node*&` (reference to non-const pointer to const). (Yes I know it's confusing... :) )

Answer (score 1):

```
const Node* &p
// p is a reference to a pointer to a constant 'Node'
```

And what you have is

```
Node *p
//  ^^ discarding the const qualifier is an error
display(p);
//      ^^ error
```

Probably the easiest fix here is to live up to the promise

```
const Node *p = new Node(10);
//^^^
display(p); // OK
```

---

`void display(const Node*& p)` is essentially the same as

```
void display(const Node** p)
```

And the standard has a good example of why initializing it with a (non-const) `Node**` is not allowed (n4659 [conv.qual]):

```
// [ Note: If a program could assign a pointer of type T** to a pointer of type const T** (that is, if line #1
// below were allowed), a program could inadvertently modify a const object (as it is done on line #2). For
// example,
int main() {
  const char c = 'c';
  char* pc;
  const char** pcc = &pc; // #1: not allowed
  *pcc = &c;
  *pc = 'C'; // #2: modifies a const object
}
// — end note ]
```

Comment: The memory location was initially not constant but although the function was converting it into a `const Node` pointer I wonder why should it give a compilation error. I mean that the conversion is from non-constant to constant.